# Is it possible to use Chutzpah with Jenkins?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, chutzpah

I'm no experience with Jenkins, I'm currently researching different options for PHP & JS automated unit testing with Jenkins.

I've come across Chutzpah (which uses PhantomJS's headless WebKit browser) but:

#### Is it possible to use Chutzpah with Jenkins?

There's very little documentation on Chutzpah. Although it does state on the Chutzpah homepage that it can be integrated into the TeamCity continuous integration server.

#### What's the minimum requirements for something to be compatible with Jenkins?

Comment: @downvoter I don't understand how this isn't constructive as it would fill holes in the documentation. A comment explaining what's wrong with the question would be helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to use Chutzpah with Jenkins and with the 2.1 release of Chutzpah it is easier. Chutzpah's command line client can now take /junit argument that lets you specify a file name to output a junit-xml compatible file to. You can use Jenkins to pick this file up and report the test results.

Answer (score 2):

I am not the downvoter, but I agree it is difficult to give a good answer to this question.

I believe the minimum requirement for something to be compatible with Jenkins is: It can be executed from a shell or cmd script. (If it's not, you need to find or write a plugin.)

Additionally, the thing should exit with code 0 for success and anything else for failure. (If it doesn't, you need to find or write a plugin.)

If you are interested in having Jenkins publish test results, the results must be in xml files using junit compatible notation. (If they are not, you need find or write a plugin.)

Additional requirements might be imposed by the tool you want to execute: It might need to draw windows or access the mouse or other parts of a graphical UI desktop/session. If that's the case, you need to run Jenkins in a context/session where it has access to those. (Windows, Mac and Linux all restrict background daemon/service access to the GUI desktop.)

Also, if your tool needs to access resources which are accessible by only certain user, you need to run Jenkins as that user.

This is a very open-ended question. Please try it out and come back with more concrete questions.

Comment: To get back to the original Chutzpah with Jenkins question, if you happen to live near Vancouver, your question might be covered at this meeting:  http://www.meetup.com/Vancouver-Software-Test-Automation-Group/events/68332052/